# How to concat parameter of a function within a variable name

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark-sql, parameter-passing

I may have not asked the question correctly but let say I want to use the name of whatever parameter i pass in to my function, to have my variable within that function to be named ;

```
def myFunc(dfName: DataFrame): Unit = {
  
  val "{dfName}_concatenated" = dfName

}
```

so if i passed in myFunc(testDf) the variable inside should be named `testDf_concatenated`

Comment: Using variables within variable names is not a good practice. Use maps for this purpose.

Comment: I would advice not use variable names as some parameters it would bring you difficulties while refactoring. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What exactly do you expect to find at `"{dfName}_concatenated"`?

Comment: Sound like you are trying to write **Python** in **Scala**, thus this seems to be an XY-question. - It would be better if you explain what you want to do, what is the meta-problem you are trying to solve instead on focusing on this specific solution you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Values and variables have to be named at compile time and this process you're looking for needs to be done at runtime, so you can not do it this way, try using a simple name and the value would be a `Map("{whatever}_concatenated" -> ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure what is your question, will that work for you?

```
def myFunc(dfName: String, anotherParam: Int): Unit = {
  val dfNameConcatenated = s"${dfName}_concatenated"
}
```

Comment: I think he/she wants to name the variable dynamically! like:
    `val $someNameInjectedAtRuntime = "SomeStringOrWhatever"`